# program need to find count of all the successor of parent number entered in the parent box on click

Tags: javascript

**Relation box** should accept list of numbers separated by space. first number is parent and remaining  numbers in the same line are children of this parent .each line defines new parent child relation program.
I need to find count of all the successor (not  only immediate successor) of parent  number entered in the parent box on click of show button 
(using *java script*)
**sample input and output**:

```
1 Relation: 1 2 3 4 5
            2 6 7
            3 8 9
            6 10
            7 11
           11 12 13
parent: 2
Successor: 6

2.Relation: 1 2 3 4 5
            2 6 7
            3 8 9
            6 10
            7 11
           11 12 13
parent: 5
Successor: 0

3.Relation: 1 2 3 4 5
            2 6 7
            3 8 9
            6 10
            7 11
           11 12 13
parent: 7
Successor: 3
```

Comment: Hello @prathmesh welcome on SO. Though we are willing to help you improve your knowledge and code, we won't write code for you.
Also: Java and JavaScript are not the same. just to get you started.

Comment: If this should be homework it is essential that you show us what you have tried so far or at least describe the problems you are facing.

Comment: yes its possible in javascript